# Find with specific content in mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, pymongo

Hi how can i find data with some specific query. For example, i have a collection in below:

```
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "05"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "06"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "07"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "08"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "04"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2021",
    "month" : "05"
}
```

So i want to get data "centId" is must be "261FB12F", "servId" is must be "CBBFEC62", "year" is not be "2020" and "month" is not be "06" too. How can i send query. I want result like below:

```
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "06"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "07"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "08"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2020",
    "month" : "04"
},
{
    "centId" : "261FB12F",
    "servId" : "CBBFEC62",
    "year" : "2021",
    "month" : "05"
}
```

Comment: You say "year" is not be "2020" and all your examples but the last one has 2020. The first one has month = "06" - could you please clarify your selection criteria.

Comment: Yes "year" not equal to "2020" and "month" not equal to "06". and "centId" must equal to  "261FB12F" and "centerId" must equal to "CBBFEC62"

Comment: How can your results have "2020" or "06" when you say not equal?

Comment: So i want to get data "centId" is must be "261FB12F", "servId" is must be "CBBFEC62", "year" is not be "2020" and "month" is not be "06" too.

Answer (score 1):

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $and: [
        {
          $eq: [
            "$centId",
            "261FB12F"
          ]
        },
        {
          $eq: [
            "$servId",
            "CBBFEC62"
          ]
        },
        {
          $ne: [
            "$year",
            "2020"
          ]
        },
        {
          $ne: [
            "$month",
            "06"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UodA6eDb1dJ)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want to use Mongo's [logical](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-logical/) expressions. specifically the [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operator in your case:

```
db.collection.find({
    $and: [
        {centerId: "A"},
        {ServiceId: "B"},
        {country: {$ne: "Georgia"}},
        {city: {$ne: "Batumi"}}
    ]
})
```

Comment: Thanks my friend for help but your code is not working in my special example. Although this example like my special example

Comment: You have a different issue then, either querying the wrong collection or database, if you do an empty `find` query you see results?

Comment: My friend i replaced example code with my actual code,please let try on actual collection

Answer (score 0):

```
db.getCollection("mycollection").find({
    "centerId": "A",
    "ServiceId": "B",
    "country": {
        $ne: 'Georgia'
    },
    city: {
        $ne: 'Batumi'
    }
})
```

Comment: @Vagif  Please replace collection name with your actual collection name in query and then execute